# Can I securely erase a HDD larger than 2TB on a laptop without UEFI support?

Tags: hard-drive, uefi, mbr, secure-erase

I would like to securely erase a WD 6TB HDD.

The problem is that the only computer I have access to in the house which can run uninterrupted (for the 2.5 days I estimate this will take) is a [2009 Samsung NC10 netbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_NC10) which doesn't support UEFI.

This means that both [Darik's Boot and Nuke](https://dban.org/) and Linux boot using MBR and therefore see the drive as only 2TB in size.

How can I securely erasing the whole 6TB using the netbook I’ve got?

Comment: The reason the software reports the drive as something other than 6 TB is due to it only supporting MBR and not UEFI.  **It has nothing to do with it being a 32-bit environment.**  All you have to do is use an environment that supports UEFI.  MBR does not support more than 2 TB HDDs.

Comment: @Ramhound It would appear that my laptop doesn’t support UEFI. In fairness it was purchased in 2009.

Comment: You could try alternative mechanisms of erasing the data - like deleting everything then writing random data to files. When you need to stop, turn off the writes, then resume, or partition the disk into multiple partitions and do 1 partition per day.

Comment: Even if a Linux system boots via MBR shoudn't it still be able to see a second drive as full capacity (and use it as GPT) ? The MBR limit only applies to boot-drives as far as I know.

Comment: @Tonny is right, UEFI and MBR are not opposites. OS boot mode is not related to partitioning scheme. A disk is just a bunch of bytes no matter how it's partitioned.

Comment: @Tonny I tried booting with Linux but `fdisk -l` reported the second drive's total size as a shade under 2TB. I even installed gparted but it stated exactly the same thing, just in a more visual way! Both my NAS (no free slots) and Windows 10 PC (can't allocate to this task) reports it as being 6TB, so I know it's not a dodgy disk.

Comment: @Richard With GParted try to see if you can give it a fresh GPT partition table. Chances are that at that point it will see full capacity. If that doesn't work. How are you connecting the disk to the computer? Directly Sata or USB converter cable/USB enclosure? If USB the Sata/USB chip in between could be part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ramhound is wrong with his UEFI requirement because that applies only to booting from drives bigger than 2TB (if it all). I have a machine running Windows 7 64 bit that is starting from a MBR and is accessing a secondary drive with 3TB in size without problems.

Davidgo ignores that his method does not solve the issue of not accessing the last 4TB out of 6TB.

Tonny and gronostaj are right.
Tonny found the most likely problem.

I would doublecheck under Linux with hdparm.

https://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm

Check out both variants:

1. hdparm -i /dev/sdb or hdparm -i /dev/hdb
2. hdparm -I /dev/sdb or hdparm -I /dev/hdb

to see if there is any difference between what your drive reports and what your OS is supposing the drive is.

If there is a discrepancy I would assume like Tonny that there is a hardware issue.
Unfortunately I can't find an expresscard slot where you could put in a current USB3.0-controller card which would provide you with unlimited access to all sectors of your 6TB drive.

There may be one alternative left:
Use a software that supports the "ATA security erase feature".
As far as I know that would only send the erase command to the drive and does not require full 6TB via the interface.

Maybe hdparm does that as well, I forgot.
At least the Parted Magic live edition does provide a GUI based software for that issue.
The only disadvantage is that still won't have access to the upper 4TB to control the deletion process with a hex editor.
But it may be that the drive won't zero out the disk. Instead it may always use encryption and when triggering the command it will just forget the current encryption key which would be equivalent to deleting.

Good luck!

Comment: Tried creating a GPT partition table under Linux and, although it reported no error, both gparted and df reported that it was still MBR. In the end I connected it to a Windows machine, did the conversion there (which worked), put it back on the Linux machine and it also worked. What a faff!